# typesense facet products by categories

Tags: typesense

I'm a bit new to type sense, but what I want to do is to get all the categories with the number of products for each category, I think it can be done with the usage of facet, right?

Let's say my product document schema is like this:

```
{
   "name" : "products",
   "fields" : [
       {
           "name" : "id",
           "type" : "string"
       },
       {
           "name": "name",
           "type": "string"
       }, 
       {
           "name": "categories",
           "type": "object[]",
           "facet": true,
           "fields" : [
               {
                   "name":"id",
                   "type": "string"
               },
               {
                   "name":"label",
                   "type": "string"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "name": "options",
           "type": "string[]",
           "facet": true
       }
      
   ] 
}
```

so here each product can belong to one or to multiple categories (if category product belong to is subcategory that means the product also belongs to parent category) and `categories` field set to be `facet` as I want to get all the categories with the amount of products in each.

When I'm running search query like this:

```
client.collections('products').documents().search(
   {
      "q" : "*",
      "facet_by" : "categories.id",
      "per_page" : 0 # I do not need products just the facet part
   }
)
```

typesense returns random 9 facet fields like this:

```
"facet_counts" => array:1 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "counts" => array:10 [
        0 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106581
          "highlighted" => "ab58454c-def8-431f-ad78-b435e390d095"
          "value" => "ab58454c-def8-431f-ad78-b435e390d095"
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106580
          "highlighted" => "1b4dfa36-c66d-4cc0-a61d-3fee6b878299"
          "value" => "1b4dfa36-c66d-4cc0-a61d-3fee6b878299"
        ]
        2 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106550
          "highlighted" => "fe1633c0-7cd6-4f7c-88ed-f6b9de34d94d"
          "value" => "fe1633c0-7cd6-4f7c-88ed-f6b9de34d94d"
        ]
        3 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106547
          "highlighted" => "9e794fee-b3fd-4f83-a41c-cbf629bec8cf"
          "value" => "9e794fee-b3fd-4f83-a41c-cbf629bec8cf"
        ]
        4 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106543
          "highlighted" => "b94f2647-f850-48b3-861e-d9fd97cfe577"
          "value" => "b94f2647-f850-48b3-861e-d9fd97cfe577"
        ]
        5 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106542
          "highlighted" => "96e281f4-3f63-411a-a517-0250e2491cf5"
          "value" => "96e281f4-3f63-411a-a517-0250e2491cf5"
        ]
        6 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106530
          "highlighted" => "455a8b50-2dc5-4683-837e-8119217b9ee1"
          "value" => "455a8b50-2dc5-4683-837e-8119217b9ee1"
        ]
        7 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106523
          "highlighted" => "7215ec95-db47-4c90-b915-349fa05191d1"
          "value" => "7215ec95-db47-4c90-b915-349fa05191d1"
        ]
        8 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106507
          "highlighted" => "59171caf-cc00-4b7b-92dd-0da54b925a95"
          "value" => "59171caf-cc00-4b7b-92dd-0da54b925a95"
        ]
        9 => array:3 [
          "count" => 106506
          "highlighted" => "4128454d-2c26-4ed4-b194-021426a5f99e"
          "value" => "4128454d-2c26-4ed4-b194-021426a5f99e"
        ]
      ]
      "field_name" => "categories.id"
      "sampled" => false
      "stats" => array:1 [
        "total_values" => 1696
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

but in the collection there are many more categories, what I'm doing wrong? How can I get all the categories with product amounts, or it's not possible with facets?

UPD: I also have option that is a list of product-related filter ids, and I want a separate query to do the same (get all filters with product amounts), it's probably another story, just explaining why it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of facet values returned is `10` by default.

So you want to set `max_facet_values: 999999` as a search parameter to get additional facet values.

This is documented under the table [here](https://typesense.org/docs/0.25.2/api/search.html#faceting-parameters).